# Sharpening rise and fall time of square wave

Tags: level-translation

I have designed a custom PCB using [SN74LVCT145](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwijrKuxxMvmAhWyxTgGHUr7DNAQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1t45&usg=AOvVaw3pbgT92HKiEzszLt0xrm54). The board is providing desired results up to 4MHz of frequency. From 5MHz to 20MHz the output waveform is not as desired.

Edit 4: Can someone suggest any changes to schematic ?

Edit 3:-
R53=removed R25=80.6R and I soldered 18pf on top of R25(as parallel)

**5MHz output**

[image]

**7MHz output**

[image]

Edit 3:-
R53=100K R25=120R and I solder 47pf on top of R25(as parallel)

**5MHz output**

[image]

**7MHz output**

[image]

EDIT2:- 
Please find the updated schematic

R53=R55=80.6R R55=7PF and R53=49.9K R25=R26=100R
[image]

I have attached the schematic snapshot:

R1 and R10 = 4.7pF and there are 50 ohm series resistance at both input and output.

[image]

I am using 75ohm BNC to BNC cable for both feeding the input and for output.

Is it possible to adjust the rising and falling edges and make it as close as possible to square wave?

**5MHz INPUT**

[image]

**15MHz INPUT**

[image]

**20MHz INPUT**

[image]

**5MHz**

[image: 5MHZ]

**8MHz**

[image: 8MHZ]

**10MHz**

[image: 10MHZ]

**15MHz**

[image: 15MHZ]

**20MHz**

[image: 20MHZ]

Edits:-
I have added input snaps. I need 5V to 1.8V level translation from B to A.
VCCB= 5V and VCCA=1.8V. Direction pin is tied to GND

Comment: Why have you given the resistors' values in picofarads?

Comment: Where are you measuring the waveform (where did you connect the oscilloscope?)

Comment: What does the source waveform look like?

Comment: Have you made measurements without the coax?

Comment: those high-value resistors (R1 and R10) caused effects on the duty cycle of the output, so we replcaed them with capcitors.

Comment: More than anything else, it looks like the load is too much for the IC - and by "load" I mean the cable.  Cables have capacitance.

Comment: A 100k resistor shouldn't mess with your signal, especially since you are working with low impedance cables.  Something isn't right.

Comment: What alternative you would suggest for those cables?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the cables.  I don't know why they are there.  What I'm saying is that 100k shouldn't bother your signals if the source is made to drive the cables.

Comment: And, I'm not sure that IC is intended to drive low impedance cables.

Comment: The output from board will be driving 75ohm BNC connectors in the end application, so i am testing with those cables

Comment: Can you post the input waveforms as well as what your VCCA and VCCB voltages are?

Comment: @BenWatson I have added the information you have asked.

Comment: With Vcc=1.8V the drive strength of the output is only a few mA. If you want a sharp edge add another high speed buffer designed for 1.8V

Comment: _"I am using 75ohm BNC to BNC cable for both feeding the input and for output"_ how long are the cables, and what is at the other end of each?

Comment: Cable: - https://catalog.belden.com/index.cfm?event=pd&p=PF_8218  
There are 75-ohm male BNC connectors at both ends. Cable is approximately 100cm

Comment: why are you using non-std cable? and not matched termination?

Comment: Can you recommend any standard cable? 
I have terminated 80.06R both at input and output to ground

Comment: Why do you use 80R shunts for both I/O instead of adding series R to match the long path impedance?  The Zout is ~ 20 Ohms so shunting 80 R does not match impedance.  You need a switched current source for that like RS485.  So dont shunt and define purpose , path length , specs etc

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Can u recommend component values for my schmetics to test?

Comment: Specs are for 5V to 1.8V conversion. Path length in terms of ?

Comment: Why did you use coax? just for measurement? l  or other purpose? If you want a text book waveform, then define purpose and load if real or just to match path impedance?  A level shifter on a PCB or between?  I cant suggest values becuase it has no purpose and has wrong shunt loads with no series R and no target IC  . this should not taken a dozen question to answer

Comment: what changes do you want me to make to the schematic?

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've posted images of the input as well as the output, I'd say you've got a couple of problems that add up to cause what you are seeing on the output.

1. The output isn't quite capable of driving the 75ohm cable at the output.  The curved edges (both rising and falling) look to me like they've been through a low pass filter - say, the (resistive) impedance of the driver into the capacitance of the cable.  Your capacitor in place of R9 contributes to this as well.
2. Your source isn't capable of driving the 75 ohm cable, either.  Additionally, the rising edge of the signal seems to get slower as the frequency rises.

The SN74LVCT145 tries to sharpen the edges of the input signal, but has its own problems driving the output load.

---

I don't know how you'd properly solve this.

I'd start by removing the capacitors you have in place of R1 and R9.  Just **nothing** in those positions.

You'll need a line driver to handle the output side.  Something like the [SN74LVC3G34](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC3G34)

That would also handle the level translation.  It can accept up to 5V on the input, even when powered by 1.8V. 5V logic level signal in, power on 1.8V, 1.8V logic level out.

Using the SN74LVC3G34 instead of the SN74LVCT145 is only possible since you say you only need to translate the levels in one direction (you have DIR set to a fixed value in your circuit.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting [reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient).

[image]

Try a series 75 ohm resistor with A and B as source termination.

Comment: I have previously tried and the results are same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast rise and fall time, you need a driver that can source and sink enough current to drive your outputs interface - a 75 ohm BNC to coax in this case.

Your post showed the original waveform below for 20 MHz. 
[image]

The slow edges is just a manifestation of having too weak of a driver.

This waveform, I think is after you added some source termination resistors:

[image]

That little pedestal or porch you see on the rising & falling edge is what you expect with a source termination scheme.  The output voltage is dividing between the output resistance of the driver+source_res and the impedance of the cable.  The voltage rises to it's full value after the reflection from the destination comes back along the cable.

If you need fast edges (you haven't said how fast they need to be), you need a fast, strong driver and an interface from your driver to the load that's all at the same impedance.  That sounds like it needs to be 75 ohms in this case.

Comment: I am using the Scientific-SMG2122 Signal generator for testing the board. So you're saying this generator isn't providing enough source/sink current?

Comment: From the data sheet for the SMG2122, the rise and fall time (10% to 90%) for a square wave output under "square characteristics" is spec'd as 9 ns, which is close to what your 'scope traces are showing.  Under "Pulse Characteristics", it says 8.4 ns to 22.4 ns.  If you want faster edges, you should probably look for a pulse generator, and not an AWG.

Comment: And you still haven't told us what kind of edges (how fast) you're looking for.

Comment: I need output which as close as possible to a square wave with 50% TON and TOFF

Comment: "50% TON and TOFF".  I'm sorry, but I don't understand what that means in this context.  50% of what?  Are you talking about the duty cycle of the square wave?  I'm asking about the edge rates; the rise and fall times to go from OFF to ON and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I was talking about duty cycle

Comment: Why are you using 75 coax?  What do you really need?  square wave +/- 0.1%?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have mismatched load impedance, but I have no idea what the real impedances you had, when the signals were captured.

From the datasheets for 5V logic.

Vol=0.55 max @ 32mA means **Zol=17 Ohms**  @ 32mA = pullup of 125 Ohms to 4.5V
Voh= 4.5V-0.7V=3.8Vmin means **Zoh=22 Ohms** @ 32 mA  = Load of 102 Ohms to 0V

If you want textbook waveforms, insert 50 to 55 Ohms in series with driver at source.. to drive 75 Ohm Coax.  If not using coax in final circuit  then define transmission line.

If you really need to drive 75 Ohm coax and want clean signal terminate it with 75 Ohms and suffer the 50% loss.  You can tie it to Vdd/2 instead of ground for symmetry.

This also means DC resistance without probe inductance and coax mismatched impedance.

Then you must decide how much current you wish to drive as the Zol and Zoh as you need to terminate this with an active load for best results with active voltage set to the desired threshold such as Vdd/2.

This means based on your desired voltage swing , asymmetry of transition time, skew of duty cycle you may need to specify an acceptance criteria before a good solution can be made.

### Problem

What you have shown are distorted waveforms of overshoot and ringing. THIS DOES NOT MATTER and is not big enough to cause a data error.

What may matter to you more is the Asymmetry error from 50%.... is my guess but you never specified it.

You also never specified your actual load, only that you measured it with 75 Ohm Coax and no termination.

Answer (score -2):

Looking on datasheet (your link) I found, that while Vcc is about `1.8V`, the output current (source/sink) is limited to `4mA` only (see `table 7.3`). Lets assume L/H or H/L transition (`0.45V->1.2V` or `1.2V->0.45V`, so about `0.8V` swing) on output: the dynamic output impedance is circa `0.8V/4mA = 200ohm`. Cable impedance is `75ohm`, so the best matching resistance will be equal `sqrt(200ohm * 75ohm) = ~120ohm`. For compensation of cable capacitance you need to add capacitor in parallel to this `120ohm`. I don't know the exact cable capacitance, but we can see (on your snaps) that the trailing/failing slope of output pulse is about `20...25mV/ns` in worst case, so - taking in head maximum sink/source current equal `4mA` - cable capacitance is probably equal circa `4mA / 20...25mV/ns = 200...160pF`. So, my experience says that the parallel capacitance connected to matching resistor (`120ohm`) should be `0.3...1 * cable capacitance = 48...200pF`. Simply try playing with this, starting from, for example, `47pF`, and going up to, for example, `220pF`. Of course, in case of visible oscillations, try add `10...22ohm` in serial to this RC circuit (so, in serial to output). `And final NOTE:` my calculations are very approximate, so the real, optimal values, can differ significantly (maybe -50%...+100%) - but without knowledge of all parameters there is no possibility to calculate this exactly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102620/discussion-on-answer-by-villagetech-sharpening-rise-and-fall-time-of-square-wave). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).